# Is there a way to use the requirements.txt file when deploying a Django App with Azure CLI?

Tags: django, azure, command-line-interface

It seems that the requirements.txt file is automatically recognized and executed when using the github continous integration. Would it be possible to do this with Azure CLI?

Comment: This answer should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840209/azure-deployment-not-installing-python-packages-listed-in-requirements-txt

Comment: Thanks @GaëtanGR but I think that the `.skipPythonDeployment` file is unique to github deployment. Couldn't find it in my case.